# How do I keep a user logged in to an application on Android?

Tags: android, cookies

When a user logs in to my online android application, I want to store a cookie on the user's phone so that he doesn't have to log in to the application on subsequent visits from the same phone.

How do I do this on android?

Comment: If it's just a website then just do it as normal using the Set-Cookie header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at using `SharedPreferences`.  Preferences are stored on a per application basis and are private to the application by default.  Basically, once the user supplies valid credentials, you'd save them to a `SharedPreferences` object and use it next time the user logs in.

Comment: Exactly, i have to use SharedPreferences in my application and it's a best way to store credentials.